# How to create a search engine using elastic search in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, elasticsearch, kibana

I want to create a search engine using elastic search where i want the postgressql data sync with elastic search database and get the scalable results.

I try elastic enterprise search but not finding any proper solution. I hope you guys give some solutions.

Comment: What problem you facing? There is many tutorials on internet teaching how to build NodeJs search api.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad and there might be multiple ways to do it.
You may follow below approach to achieve this

1. Setup the Elasticsearch Cluster based on your data need.
2. Figure out right `analyzer` based on search type you are planning to support ( e.g fulltext, exact match ).
   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analyzer.html
   https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-text-analysis-part-1
   [What is Analyzer in Elasticsearch for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51807333/what-is-analyzer-in-elasticsearch-for)
3. Data Indexing:

   - Figure out how you will index data from Postgres to Elasticsearch. You can use custom mapping while indexing the data based required analyzer you will figure out in step #2. For indexing please check [Logstash jdbc input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html). I have used it for MySQL but you can check if it supports Postgres as well. Please find below references
     [Reference 1](https://medium.com/@emreceylan/how-to-sync-postgresql-data-to-elasticsearch-572af15845ad)
     [Reference 2](https://github.com/zombodb/zombodb)
     For NodeJS: [NodeJs + Postgresql + ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60558349/nodejs-postgresql-elasticsearch)